# "Как-то так"— какой статус у выражения?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В последнее время в устной речи можно часто слышать оборот "как-то так". Им завершают утвердительные фразы, а также вопросительные предложения. Иногда его даже вставляют и в письменные контексты. Когда я формулировал настоящий вопрос, один из примеров высветился даже на данном сайте, посвященном грамотной речи и проблемам русского языка: "Так что как-то так". Этим выражением завершается формулировка вопроса, то есть ни для автора, ни для модераторов оно не представляется чем-то инородным, не воспринимается как ненормативное, является органичным и естественным). Однако, на мой взгляд, статус выражения "как-то так" является достаточно неопределенным. С чем мы имеем дело здесь? С очередным словом-паразитом или новым междометием, добавляющем в нашу речь не выражаемые другими междометиями оттенки эмоционального смысла? В любом случае, на мой взгляд, его неуместно употреблять в письменной речи, тем более в текстах вопросов на темы русского языка.

Comment: По-моему, по статусу не отличается от давно известного "вот так" или посто "вот".

Comment: По значению, наверно, да, но не по экспрессии, которая в "как-то так" носит более интенсивный, несколько "играющий". "улыбающийся" характер; окраска этого выражения также более снижена, отличается подчеркнутой   разговорностью.

Comment: Я всегда уважаю тех, кто так говорит. За то, что они не претендуют на абсолютную истину, что не считают свои слова безупречными и понимают, что собеседник их мог понять не совсем хорошо не только из-за того, что невнимательно слушал. Это хорошие, скромные люди. Мне никогда не казалось, что это выражение мусорное, но с интересом послежу за ответами. Может быть, и меня в этом всё-таки убедят (если это действительно похоже на правду).

Comment: Я ни в коем случае не утверждаю, что это выражение - мусорное. Мои слова о "слове-паразите" - лишь способ заострить вопрос. Сам я склоняюсь ко второму ответу: здесь присутствует особый эмоциональный смысловой оттенок, но разговорность оборота - очевидная, и, при строгом отношении к соблюдению нормы, в официальной ситуации (а формулировка вопроса несет в себе момент официальности) оно, как мне кажется, не должно употребляться. Как-то так. :)

Comment: :) Ну хорошо, подождём ответов. :)

Answer (score 4):

**1.** Думаю, что выражение имеет "разговорный статус".
Оно есть в [Словаре синонимов](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/334616/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA):
 **как-то так**
наречие; синонимы: *приблизительно, что-то типа*.

**2.** Нельзя сказать, что выражение новое.
Посмотрите, похожее есть у Н. В. Гоголя в "Ревизоре" (1835):

[Хлестаков]  *С Пушкиным на дружеской ноге. Бывало, часто говорю ему: "Ну что, брат Пушкин?" — "Да так, брат, — отвечает, бывало, — **так как-то** всё..." Большой оригинал.*

Есть оно и у [В. В. Высоцкого](https://stihi-russkih-poetov.ru/poems/vladimir-vysockiy-istoma-yashchericey-polzaet-v-kostyah) (1971):

*Не пью воды — чтоб стыли зубы — питьевой

И ни событий, ни людей не тороплю,

Мой лук валяется со сгнившей тетивой,

Все стрелы сломаны — я ими печь топлю.*

*Не напрягаюсь, не стремлюсь, а **как-то так**...

Не вдохновляет даже самый факт атак.

Сорвиголов не принимаю и корю,

Про тех, кто в омут головой, — не говорю.*

Считаю, здесь оборот *абсолютно к месту,* что-то иное уже и не представляется.

Есть и другие авторы, которые его используют вполне литературно, без паразитизма, но, действительно, — с особыми эмоциями и с особым акцентом на нём:

*Растворился кафе полумрак

В догорающей тихо свече.

Как дела? Как живу? — **Как-то так**,

Не доспав на любимом плече.*
*Просто выцвел со временем взгляд,

А в твоих — как тогда, бирюза...*
Т. Бунтина

***Как-то так*** получается, что к человеку старшему, умудренному опытом, мы прислушиваемся не сразу, поначалу пренебрегаем советами, и только набив собственные шишки, вспоминаем о предостережениях (Лев Портной. "Акведук на миллион").

**3.** Мне кажется, что главное — не злоупотреблять, не повторять "по-эллочко-людоедски", и тогда выражение не будет выглядеть инородным, ненормативным.

Дополнительно: [**как-то так**](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&lex1=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%BE&startyear=1994&lex2=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA&max2=1&text=lexgramm&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&level1=0&level2=0&endyear=2014&mode=main&parent1=0&min2=1&nodia=1&parent2=0&p=0) (НКРЯ).

Answer (score 3):

Когда нету в речи говорящего ни неопределённого, ни неуместного на письме?

Допустим, творческая работа в процессе и она демонстрируется заказчику по его настоятельной просьбе, которую нельзя игнорировать. Какой же автор не скажет — «как-то так», — давая всем видеть незаконченное изделие? Об этом не было договорённости, но он переживёт вмешательство. Здесь налицо спокойствие профи и желание не тратить время на незапланированные совещания. Для тех, с кем он на короткой ноге, у него, предположу, имеется более радушный вариант — разговорный, типа *вот так вот-то вот*.

Возможно, что причина некой неопределённости объясняется заложенным в наречии ***как*** вопроса, но в данной фразе являющимся союзом. Стало быть, дело в интонации и её правильной передаче средствами пунктуации. Так же, как в случае с ***почему*** (местоимение, союз и т. д.), — выступая не как вопросительное наречие оно вполне твёрдо: «Почему-то это меня не удивляет».

Answer (score 1):

Словосочетание "как-то так" в советские годы я не видел в письменной речи так часто, как сейчас. Точнее вообще не встречал, хотя читать люблю.Считаю это словосочетание в наше время - словом-паразитом.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вы - единственный, кто разделяет мои недоумения по поводу использования данного выражения. Все остальные авторы и комментаторы горой стоят за него.

Comment: @БорисБобылев Вы не совсем точны в своих комментариях. Посмотрите ещё раз в моем ответе: _...используют вполне литературно, без паразитизма, но, действительно, — с особыми эмоциями и с особым акцентом..._ И в конце: _Мне кажется, что главное — не злоупотреблять, не повторять "по-эллочко-людоедски", и тогда выражение не будет выглядеть **инородным, ненормативным**._ Мне понравился Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Приношу извинения. Я, действительно, был слишком категоричен. Благодарю за положительную оценку вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

С моей точки зрения это сочетание уже перешло в разряд устойчивых и не должно восприниматься логически. Примеры: так-сяк, ни то ни сё.

Answer (score 0):

добавление в конце повествования фразы "как-то так" призвано обозначить некую "неокончательность", черновиковость сообщенного...мол, вы посмотрите, а мы, если нужно, подправим...на наш взгляд, модное и совершенно лишнее клише...с претензией.

Comment: А современная мода начинать предложения со строчных букв — это на ваш взгляд хорошо? Вот я смотрю на ваши многоточия и не могу понять, то ли они заканчивают предложения, то ли это тоже веяние моды — стенографировать на письме внутреннюю речь.

Comment: Вы правы. Это, безусловно, плохо. Однако, мода тут не при чем. Так чаще всего пишу я. Для собственного удобства. Что, повторюсь, соглашаясь, нехорошо. Со стороны вполне может показаться претенциозным. Относительно как бы стенографирования размышлений вслух - определено Вами совершенно точно. Только разве мы говорили обо мне?

Comment: Речь о Вашем ответе, если угодно. Поймите правильно: здесь, на сайте, принято не писать как удобно.

Comment: Куда я попал? Прелесть какая...

Comment: Вы попали в общество любителей русского языка. Если запомните, что "не при чем" пишется так: "ни при чём", тогда, значит, зашли не зря :)

Answer (score 0):

Лично у меня это выражение вызывает негативное отношение: тот, кто заканчивает свою мысль "как-то так", будто сам не удосужился её продумать, но мнение имеет. Может, я и предвзят, потому что чаще всего видел "как-то так" у людей, не терпящих другого мнения, но притворяющихся, что они не доминируют, а "как-то так". 
Если у человека есть идея, в которой он сомневается, есть другие способы выразить "черновиковость" мысли. "Как-то так" - это халтура, но "пипл схавает, это моя страница, бан".